# How to use ajax for send data to api action in another project

Tags: c#, ajax, api

i acan use ajax and api action in one project and send data and update data correctly.
but when i want to send data from ajax in my project to api action in my another project,the api action dont work!

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: urll,
    error: function() {
        alert("errore")
    },
    data: {
        id: 4
    },
    success: function(dataa) {
        alert("ok");
        var x = JSON.stringify(dataa, null, '\t');
        var dataaa = $.parseJSON(x);
        alert(dataaa.price);
        dataa.price -= 1.02;
        var url2 = 'https://localhost:44337/api/apiialbums/PutAlbum';
        //var url2 = 'http://localhost:51111/api/AlbumsApi/PutAlbum';
        $.ajax({
            type: "PUt",
            //async: false,
            url: url2,
            //data: JSON.stringify(dataa, null, '\t'),
            data: {
                album: dataa
            },
            //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", ///////
            //dataType:"json",
            success: function(dataaz) {
                alert("updated");
                alert(dataaz.price);
                var x2 = JSON.stringify(dataaz, null, '\t');
                alert(x2);
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("error in update..");
            }
        })
    }
});
```

and my api [httpput]action:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<ActionResult<Album>> PutAlbum([FromBody]Album album)
{
    _context.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); return album;
}
```

when i breakpoint in api action,
I understand that the program does not refer to the action

I searched the internet a lot but I could not find the reason, please help me to solve this problem as soon as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my asp.net core project, i use following code in ConfigureServices in startup:

```
 services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("*")/*.AllowAnyOrigin()*/.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });
```

in we can use the client url instead of * :

```
  .WithOrigins("http://localhost:51111")
```

and in startup in Configure use :

```
  <pre>  app.UseCors();</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite probable that you haven't enabled cross-origin requests. As it is stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api):

> Browser security prevents a web page from making AJAX requests to another domain. This
> restriction is called the same-origin policy, and prevents a malicious
> site from reading sensitive data from another site. However, sometimes
> you might want to let other sites call your web API.

So you have to enable first Cors. For that reason, you should go in the WebConfig class of the WebAPI that you want to be called and put the following line anywhere inside the `Register` method:

```
  config.EnableCors();
```

Then you should go the controller, in which the `PutAlbum` is defined and decorate with the following attribute

```
[EnableCors(origins: "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net", headers: "*", methods: "PUT")]
```

You **should replace "http://mywebclient.azurewebsites.net"** with the URI of your Web Application, that you want to call your Web API.

**UPDATE**

The above apply for ASP.NET projects. For ASP.NET Core please have a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: my project is asp.net core, And no webconfig Where should I add these commands?

Comment: @reza just update my answer with a link that explains how you can do the same thing in ASP.NET Core. Please let me know, if that fixed your problem.

Comment: i use  services.AddCors(...) acording to my  services.AddCors and it work corectly. Thank you Christos

Comment: @reza You are very welcome. I am glad that I helped.